# FrameLayout не отображается поверх Button

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть `FrameLayout` в который я кладу `Button` и `FrameLayout` с целью перекрыть изображением (будущей анимацией, поэтому и `FrameLayout`) кнопку. Предпросмотр все отображает верно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, при запуске кнопка перекрывает "FrameLayout":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка:

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_auth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_refresh_36dp_1" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Почему `Button` перекрывает `FrameLayout` (хотя с аналогичной... конструкцией, в этой же разметке, такого не было. И как все же расположить `FrameLayout` поверх `Button`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вся соль здесь в таком атрибуте кнопки как `android:elevation`.

Кнопка в API > 21 имеет такой атрибут `android:stateListAnimator`, который по умолчанию ссылается на файл `button_state_list_anim_material.xml` со следующим [содержанием](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/anim/button_state_list_anim_material.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
    <!-- base state -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                            android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                            android:valueTo="0"
                            android:startDelay="@integer/button_pressed_animation_delay"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                            android:duration="0"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
...
</selector>
```

Видим что в обычном `state_enabled`-состоянии атрибут `elevation` имеет значение `@dimen/button_elevation_material`, которое [равно](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml) `2dp`.

**Вывод:** если мы хотим что бы какое то `view` перекрывало кнопку, необходимо для него(view!) использовать `android:elevation` >= `2dp`.

Comment: @bukashka101 ну во первых у меня тоже была недавно такая проблемка, я ее костыльно решил, тут увидел ваш вопрос и решил все таки  разобраться...искал по запросу типа "android button above appear view" и так как проблема присуща только для API > 21, то поставил фильтр гугла отобразить результаты только `за год`...первая же ссылка привела на enSO где в первом ответе была ссылка на подробную инфу - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27112143/4728929

Answer (score 3):

Оберните кнопку и фрейм дополнительно отдельными лайатуами, я уже у себя ловил такой баг, когда поверх Button на андройде 5.0 и выше вью которая должна была рисоваться поверх не было видно. Пока не добрался до причины, но костыльно решено было вот так.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <RelativeLayout
               .....>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_auth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
               .....>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_refresh_36dp_1" />
         </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Возможно только что, до меня дошло... AppCompat переопределяет во вью при создании стандартные виджеты и ставит свои (AppCompatButton, AppCompatTextView и др. - замечал при дебаге), так как они удаляют и добавляют, виджет Button будет иметь индекс больше чем FrameLayout, а соответственно выше по иерархии и в итоге после всех этих махинаций гугла - виджет Button лежит по верх всего остального в общем контейнере. Поправьте меня в комментарии, если это бред.

Comment: В Вашем предположении была доля истины, но Вы не дошли до реальной проблемы. Ответ выше поясняет, что именно происходило :).