# Как наложить TextView на Button?

Tags: java, android

Как наложить TextView на Button в RelativeLayout?

Comment: Что вы хотите от этого наложения получить, наверняка есть более правильное решение, чем наложение виджетов друг на друга.

Comment: У меня кнопка запускающая таймер. Я хочу чтобы на этой кнопке происходил отсчет таймера. @pavlofff

Comment: @ЛевНауменко а Вы там случаем AppCompat не используете?

Comment: Использую. @ermak0ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все из-за того, что кнопки в `API > 21` имеют атрибут `android:elevation`, в следствии чего Ваша кнопка и перекрывает `TextView`.

Добавьте в Ваш `TextView` атрибут `android:elevation = 2dp`.

Подробнее можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517251/176223).

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы TextView был поверх Button? @metalurgus

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, он и будет поверх `Button`. Чтобы убедиться - поменяйте ему цвет текста, или фон

Comment: Я не знаю, что я не так делаю, но все равно текст под кнопкой. @metalurgus

Answer (score 0):

использовать атрибут

android:elevation="100dp"

---

или
android:translationZ="100dp"